# En Java ¿Qué podría estarme creando sesiones web de la nada?

Tags: java, aplicación-web, servlets, sesiones

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo una aplicación web de Java en la que utilizo sesiones para validar al usuario.

Tengo una clase `listener` que me envía un mensaje al `log` cada vez que es creada o destruida una sesión.

La aplicación está desplegada en JBOSS EAP 6 en cluster y un balanceador de carga.

En el JBOSS tengo desplegadas otras aplicaciones que hacen uso del mismo mecanismo de las sesiones.

El problema que tengo es que revisando el `log` para una de las aplicaciones que tengo, logro observar que se crean y destruyen sesiones de la nada.

Pienso que no podría ser por el uso que le den los usuarios, que no está de más decir que son como unos 500, porque el `log` muestra registros en hora de la madrugada y en cualquier hora, prácticamente, y estos están separados casi por 5 segundos de diferencia.

Aquí una parte del log:

```
23:58:57,195 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) La sesión actual ha sido destruida :5sCDbUkkXSW2WJzE7Bd-mqME Cerrando la sesión del usuario...
23:58:57,198 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) La sesión actual ha sido destruida :6YHp0bfryOVd38oItQkO4NFZ Cerrando la sesión del usuario...
23:58:57,202 INFO  [stdout] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) La sesión actual ha sido destruida :C1OfjPzlUZsN22MNxWWd59w- Cerrando la sesión del usuario...
23:58:58,282 INFO  [stdout] (http-/172.30.1.83:8080-14) La sesión actual ha sido creada : XEJGCxnbzXgzCmIdd43P52tU at Tue Oct 18 23:58:58 CST 2016
23:59:03,311 INFO  [stdout] (http-/172.30.1.83:8080-14) La sesión actual ha sido creada : mnapuwCBfx5WPkaH6qdygrYa at Tue Oct 18 23:59:03 CST 2016
23:59:08,351 INFO  [stdout] (http-/172.30.1.83:8080-14) La sesión actual ha sido creada : GgirsfhedwwFTxmX-fiI8FCe at Tue Oct 18 23:59:08 CST 2016
```

Espero alguien pueda darme una idea de lo que podría estar pasando.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿No tendrás algún servicio tipo Nagios que te monitorea que la Webapp está arriba? ¿La IP de origen es la misma del server?

Comment: Puedes intentar investigar el stacktrace para determinar si todas se crean con peticiones al mismo servlet.

Comment: que tiempo de vida tienen tus sesiones? creo que lo que estas viendo es como se recarga una sesion al final de su periodo de validez....

Answer (score 1):

He resuelto mi interrogante.

Descubrí que el balanceador de carga lo han dejado configurado para que envíe peticiones a esta aplicación con tal de que compruebe que los servidores que maneja estén activos.

Gracias por su interés en ayudarme: darkglam, SJuan76 y Jordi Castilla